# Android keyboard that doesn't insert space after the recommended word

Tags: android, keyboard

I bought smart keyboard pro few years ago and it was great. But it's missing so many options that the new keyboards offer, like gestures and so on, plus it seems like the project is dying.

I tried swiftkey, swipe, Gboard, Cheetah, chrooma, Flesky and fancy keyboards and they all seem to have features missing. I'm looking for the following features:

- The option not to insert a space after picking the recommended word.
- Gestures
- Show numbers on keys (unlike fleksy)
- Many themes
- Free (otherwise I might buy chrooma, not sure if it has all the features though)
- Optional: ability to hide the capitalization key, I hit it often by mistake instead of `A`
- Left handed mode should be available

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest [AnySoftKeyboard](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard/). i'm pretty sure it has all your required features, except the optional:

- space after picking can be en-/disabled
- a bunch of gestures can be defined
- you can choose between may designs and themes
- it is free (as in beer and speech)
- like designs and themes also numerous additional dictionaries can be installed.